# Is there a simpler way to run clippy on my build script?

Tags: rust, static-analysis, rust-cargo

In a Cargo project, I can easily run [clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy) on my `src` code using this command:

```sh
rustup run nightly cargo clippy
```

However, if I'm using a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html), I'd like to run clippy on that as well. For instance, if my `build.rs` file looks like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = "Hello, world!";
    println!("{}", foo);
}
```

I'd like to see this when I run clippy:

```
warning: use of a blacklisted/placeholder name `foo`, #[warn(blacklisted_name)] on by default
 --> build.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     let foo = "Hello, world!";
  |         ^^^
  |
  = help: for further information visit https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/wiki#blacklisted_name
```

The only way I can think of to run clippy on my build script is to copy it into a `cargo new` temporary project, run clippy, make my changes there, and copy back, but this is horribly inconvenient and quickly becomes infeasible when [build dependencies](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#build-dependencies) and the like are added to the mix.

Is there a simpler way to analyze my build script with clippy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note: This solution no longer works. The clippy plugin feature has been removed ([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/pull/2712)).**

There are two ways to use Clippy: the `cargo clippy` command and the `clippy` compiler plugin. `cargo clippy` detects the build script as a dependency of the main project, so it doesn't load the compiler plugin.

Therefore, the other option is to use the compiler plugin directly. The instructions for doing this are in [clippy's README](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/blob/master/README.md). We need to make a few adaptations for using it on the build script, though.

First, we need to add `clippy` as a build dependency:

```
[build-dependencies]
clippy = { version = "*", optional = true }

[features]
default = []
```

Adding it to `[dependencies]` instead will not work (the result is `` error[E0463]: can't find crate for `clippy` ``), as Cargo will not pass the path to dependencies to the compiler when building the build script.

Then, we need to add this at the top of `build.rs`:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(feature="clippy", feature(plugin))]
#![cfg_attr(feature="clippy", plugin(clippy))]
```

Finally, we need to build with the `clippy` feature enabled:

```sh
$ cargo build --features clippy
```

If you want to run `clippy` on both the build script and on the main project when you use the command above, add the same `clippy` dependency to `[dependencies]`, then add the `cfg_attr` attributes to the crate root(s) (`lib.rs`, `main.rs`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the problem with this approach (besides having to annotate `Cargo.toml`, `build.rs`, and `lib.rs` or `main.rs`) is that clippy only runs when the file to be analyzed is recompiled, whereas `cargo clippy` always runs clippy even if the file doesn't need to be recompiled. Is there a better way to achieve this behavior than simply making an edit to `build.rs` before running `cargo build`?

Comment: You can run `cargo clean --package <project_name>` beforehand; this'll clean both the project itself and the build script.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work; when I run that command and then run `rustup run nightly cargo build --features clippy` again, I get the clippy output for my `src` code, but not my `build.rs` file.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me with `cargo 0.17.0-nightly (71e996e 2017-01-02)`. I get the clippy output for both. Do you have an older nightly? Do you have the same problem with just `cargo clean`?

Comment: After a full `cargo clean`, clippy runs properly on `build.rs` as expected. It looks like you're right about the version; if I run `rustup default nightly`, then `cargo clean --package <project_name>`, then `cargo build --features clippy`, I get the expected output, but if I run `rustup default stable`, then `cargo clean --package <project_name>`, then `cargo +nightly build --features clippy`, I don't get the expected output.

Comment: Also, since clippy takes a `--features` option, you can run it on both `build.rs` and the `src` code by doing the `build-dependencies` and `build.rs` setup you mentioned your answer and then running `cargo +nightly clippy --features clippy`.

Comment: This method does not appear to work at present probably because the use of clippy as a compiler plugin has been deprecated: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/pull/2712